# Windows Forms Graphics: charts

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

this is my first post here after using the platform for so long to find help with my uni projects so I beg for a little patience with me n.n'

Well, I am currently developing a little program in C# using the Windows Forms Application. I am facing the following problem: there will be 9 people with their corresponding shift like morning -> 6-14, afternoon -> 14-22 and night -> 22-6 and they can make changes between one another, like Person1 does the morning shift but has applied for a change and enters 2 hours late (8-14), and Person2 is making those hours for Person1 (22-8).

I need inspiration on how can I make a visible chart in which you can see the shift to which each person was initially assigned and the actual shift they will be doing (including those mentioned possible changes). I mean, I don't know which Form can help me or how to manage this information in my DB (SQL Server).

Thanks everybody.

Comment: You can use a grid component to draw those, colour in hour blocks for each persons hour worked.

Comment: Best draw a sketch or google for something similar and then show us.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider render some sort of chart like Swim Lane diagram (but not for workflow) where you would have each people as one row entry. Each horizontal column will represent an hour of the day (should be scroll-able for at least 1 day before and 1 day after current day). Each row would have two bars. The bigger bar represent the assigned schedule.. E.g. if someone work from 6 AM to 2 PM, that bar would span the column of 6 AM to 2 PM.

Then the 2nd bar will be slightly smaller and reside inside the first bar, which represent the actual shift the person take. This way you can see when people are assigned to work and when they actually work.

Hope that make sense.